# Jenkins pipeline - "cannot invoke method on null object" on function outside the pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

i get the error above when trying to run my pipeline

tried to run it inside and outside the groovy sandBox. 
also tried debugging and it's fails on this method call "last_build_number(lastBuildToGenerateNumber)"

before adding try, catch and recursion this code was working well outside the pipeline. don't get me wrong - this code can not run inside the pipeline so i did not try it.

/*
SEIIc DPS_NIGHTLY_BUILD JenkinsFile
*/

```
def buildDescription    // for setting the build name, based on the downstream jobs name

def last_build_number(build) {
    println 'the display name is' + build.displayName
    return build.displayName
    if (build != null) {
        if(build.displayName!=null){
            println 'the display name is' + build.displayName
            return build.displayName
        }
    } 
    else {
        return '0.0.0.0'
    }
    return '0.0.0.0'
}

def autoIncBuildNightlyNumber(build) {
    def debugEnable = 1
    println 'build is: ' + build.displayName
    def lastBuildToGenerateNumber = build; //a build variable 
    def last_build_number; //last build number i.e: "52.88.0.7" or "#43"
    build_number=0;
    try{
        println 'last build to genreate from ' + lastBuildToGenerateNumber.displayName
        last_build_number = last_build_number(lastBuildToGenerateNumber);
        if (debugEnable == 1) println 'last successfull build: ' + last_successfull_build
        def tokens = last_build_number.tokenize('.')
        if (debugEnable == 1) println 'tokens: ' + tokens
        // update global variable - if it's not a legit number the crash will be catched
        build_number = tokens[3].toInteger() + 1
        if (debugEnable == 1) println 'new build number: ' + build_number
        return build_number

    } catch (e){
        if (debugEnable == 1) println 'error is ' + e
        if (debugEnable == 1) println 'build number: ' + build_number + ' is not valid. recurse now to find a valid number'
        build_number = autoIncBuildNightlyNumber(lastBuildToGenerateNumber.getPreviousBuild());
        println 'genrate ' + lastBuildToGenerateNumber
        return build_number
    } 
}

// Declarative Pipeline
pipeline {
    /*
    maximum time for this job
    */
    options { //maximum time for this job
         timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') 
    }

    environment {
        AUTO_BUILD_NUMBER = autoIncBuildNightlyNumber(currentBuild.getPreviousBuild())
        PLASTICSCM_TARGET_SERVER = "g-plasticscm-server.gilat.com:8087"
        PLASTICSCM_TARGET_REPOSITORY = "SEIIc_DPS"
        PLASTICSCM_WORKSPACE_NAME = "${env.JOB_BASE_NAME}_${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
        AUTOMATION_FOLDER = "${env.PLASTICSCM_WORKSPACE_NAME}\\Tools\\Automation"
        Branch = "/main"
        TEST_BRANCH = "/QualiTest for SW Automation"
        QUALITEST_FOLDER = "${env.PLASTICSCM_WORKSPACE_NAME}\\QualiTest for SW Automation"
        PLASTICSCM_TEST_REPOSITORY="SW_Utiles"
        PLASTICSCM_TEST_WORKSPACE = "TEST_${env.JOB_BASE_NAME}_${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
    }

    // Select target host for building this pipeline
    agent { node { label "SEIIc_DPS" } }

    // Stages to run for this pipeline
    stages {
        /*
        Checkout files from source control. In this case the pipeline use PlasticSCM plugin to checkout a branch with given parameter "Branch".
        When this stage run, it will checkout the branch in the parameter string from the defined repository and server.
        It will not
        */
        stage('SCM Checkout') {
            steps {
                cm branch: env.Branch, changelog: true, repository: env.PLASTICSCM_TARGET_REPOSITORY, server: env.PLASTICSCM_TARGET_SERVER, useUpdate: false, workspaceName: env.PLASTICSCM_WORKSPACE_NAME
                //checkOut QualiTest
                cm branch: env.TEST_BRANCH, changelog: false, repository: 'SW_Utiles', server: env.PLASTICSCM_TARGET_SERVER, useUpdate: false, workspaceName: env.PLASTICSCM_TEST_WORKSPACE
            }
        }
           }//stages
      }//pipeline
```

Comment: is it possible that currentBuild.getPreviousBuild() is null?

Comment: It would help if you can paste the whole output, so we could see exactly where "cannot invoke method on null object" is pointing at.

Comment: Ditto, can you please post the full stack trace